# Generating etags for images in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, etag

On my site, users can upload images that are displayed publicly. When the user uploads a new image, it overwrites one of their old images.

Because the images can be large, I want them to be cached. However, when the user uploads a new image, the old cached images should not be used.

The source of the dynamic images looks like this:

```
userImage.ashx?id=f488b864-0a0b-46d9-af4a-a43cd0dcf751&type=micrositePhoto
```

So I can inject headers into the response in the .ashx file if I need to.

[I've been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890918/reload-a-cached-image-with-javascript) to use etags for this purpose, but I don't know how to do this in asp.net. The `.js` and `.css` files on my site already have etags, but I don't know what is generating them. Also, any in-built systems to generate etags will probably not understand how my .ashx file works.

How do I generate etags for my site, and make it so that they work as they are supposed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that you should be able to do, for example:

```
Response.AddHeader("ETag","\"" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "\"");
```

ETags must be enclosed inside `"`

**NOTE** Obviously, once an ETag is returned with an image it needs to be the same on subsequent requests. My code above was just a proof of concept. :)

Edit: Yep, just tested and confirmed using Firebug that the Response headers do contain the Guid that I created.

Comment: This looks like it creates a new GUID on every request, which isn't really what you want - the etag should be tied to the content somehow, eg by taking a hash of the contents of the file.

Comment: @MatthewWilson of course it creates a new Guid; *It's an example*; obviously the GUID has to be the same for every request if the thing is to be cached. I will clarify it.

Comment: Thanks it's good that I can just add headers like this. Sometimes the asp.net infrastructure gets in the way. I really need some way of keeping the etags consistant though - I was thinking maybe something with CRCs? I also need to know what I'm supposed to do with etags to make them work like they're supposed to - overwriting caches and so on.

Comment: @Icarus: OK. It just seemed like you were suggesting it as a way of solving the whole problem.

Comment: @Icarus For me, `Response.AddHeader()` Didn't work I had to use `Response.Cache.SetETag()`.

Comment: @Oliver interesting. It worked for me although I didn't test in an handler as you probably did. I just added the header in a regular page.